# VSTS Feed REST API all requests return 'Page not Found' error

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am attempting to get Feed/Package information from VSTS via the REST API.  I have successfully used the REST API to access/update build definitions and variable groups.  When I issue a request such as the following (replacing {...} with the actual values), all I get back is a 404 error 'Page not found'.

`https://{accountName}.visualstudio.com/_apis/packaging/Feeds/{feedId}/packages?api-version=5.0-preview.1`

I have tried other requests in the same area (Feed/Packages) and used other api-version values and they all give me the same response.  I have had others confirm the commands I have tried are properly formatted.  I am using Basic authentication with a PAT (the same one I use for the requests that do work).

Any insights would be appreciated.

Comment: I can also reproduce the issue with 404 response. And it seems you also reported the issue from developer community (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/234664/vsts-rest-api-feeds-list-always-returns-404-not-fo.html). So please wait for the response from our feature team there.

Comment: Another person in our group reported the issue to MS about the same time as I posted this.  I appreciate the response here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this endpoint URL instead (append `.feeds` after account):

```
https://{accountName}.feeds.visualstudio.com/_apis/packaging/Feeds/{feedId}/packages?api-version=5.0-preview.1
```

Comment: This doesn't work either.  Depending on which tool I use to send the request I get one of two errors:  1) The URL cannot be reached or 2) Our services aren't available right now.  We're working to restore ...  I have tried now and then for the last couple of days just in case error 2 was actually accurate.

Comment: Try to create a new VSTS account and try again.

Comment: My current account is already tied to way too many things to try creating a new one.  So no thanks on that idea.

Comment: @melvers Append `feeds` to the URL (not feed), sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why Microsoft official documentation dont mention this but the below api does the job -

```
https://<your organization name>.feeds.visualstudio.com/_apis/packaging/Feeds/<feedID>/Packages?api-version=5.1-preview.1
```